# Functional programming, OOP and data hiding

Tags: oop, functional-programming

Everybody says that functional programming may be better than OOP because of immutability. Okay but how does FP hide or organize data better than OOP?
If I know well OOP was introduced to solve this problem because procedural paradigm doesn't do this well enough. What has FP for this?

Is FP still a better choice for everyday programming tasks than OOP if you use OOP in a good way and you don't write anemic style classes and mutable objects?

Comment: This is a rant, not a question. And there are plenty of comparisons of OOP and FP, on this site and elsewhere. And if your data is immutable, you don't need to hide it.

Comment: Functional programming is hardly a 'new paradigm'.

Comment: @d.j.brown indeed, it's older than OOP.

Comment: There is no optimal paradigm. Different paradigms has their pros and cons. FP is very good for constructing compilers.

Comment: Why do you not need to hide immutable data? Data hiding is not just against mutation but against access.
I know that FP is older but that is not widely used today. Please understand me correctly.

Comment: @mosomedve Why do you think that you can't hide data in functional programming, or that doing it is essential to object-oriented programming?

Comment: I don't know, this is why I've asked this question.

Comment: New paradigm of **Functional Programming** like **Scala** is so different from an old one (Structural Programming).

Comment: It's about implementing Business Process or System Use Cases as Functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **TL;DR**
>
> Functional programming has nothing to do with encapsulation, but most modern functional languages support encapsulation.

Encapsulation (what you call "data hiding") is an important part of modern programming, no matter the paradigm. When you develop a library, there are parts of the code that you want to hide from the user of the library.

## The OOP side

OOP languages allow you to define *private* things: attributes, methods, classes, and whatnot. Things that are private aren't accessible from outer scopes, and that's about it.

```
# Ruby

class A
  def a
    # This is public
  end

  private

  def b
    # This is private
  end
end
```

## The modular side

[Modular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) use modules in lieu of classes, but they are pretty much the same. You can define your module interface separately from the implementation.

```
(* OCaml *)

module A : sig
  (* Here is the interface *)
  val a : int -> int
end = struct
  (* Here is the implementation *)
  let a = (* This is public *)
  let b = (* This is private *)
end
```

As you can see, modular languages are as good as OOP languages at encapsulating things.

## The functional side

To put it simply, a functional language is imply a language that does not use mutation. Of course, a truer definition would be much more complicated.

Let's see an example:

```
# Python

def sum(l):
  sum = 0
  for e in l:
    sum += e # Mutations occur here
  return sum
```

And in a functional style, i.e. without any mutation:

```
(* OCaml *)

let rec sum l =
  match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | h::t -> h + sum t
```

The benefits of a functional style over an imperative one are up for discussion, but I'll leave them out of this for now.

## Putting it all together

In fact, a language does not have to choose between modular, OOP, or functional. As you can see from the above, the three concepts are truly different from one another, and languages just tend to combine these features.

OCaml, for example, is *mainly* functional and modular, but it also supports OOP and imperative style, so that you can get the best of all worlds, provided you know what you're doing. (It's a *"With great power comes great responsibility"* sort of thing.)

So, to answer your question, functional programming in itself has nothing to do with encapsulating data, but functional languages provide features such as classes or modules to do that for them.

Comment: This is a very good answer. So I should learn FP, combine with OOP and that will be a good result. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, yes. The more you know, the more you're able to choose the right solution to the right problem. You'll find that FP is very good for some problems, and OOP is better at other kinds of problem. Also, if you're sqtisfied with the answer, feel free to mark it as accepted. :)